# How does one speparete assets from the Git repository in a Unity project?

Tags: unity-game-engine, npm, assets, package-management

I would like to understand how I can manage many larger packages which contain assets for unity, that I can load into different projects.
The following picture should demonstrate my goal:
[Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZZF63.png)
A standard package manager, say npm, would be exactly this, but cannot contain very large packages.
I thought of creating docker images as packages but that sounds more lika a hack than an actual solution.
To be clear, my problem is solely the package manager side of the graphic, I do not require help with creating the references and such.

I have tried using npm, but encountered the size issue pretty fast:
[Error 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sXA9J.png)
Even when breaking down, the issue remained with:
[Error 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MXSos.png)
Pretty much also a sizing issue from what I researched. And at this point I would have required an unrealistic amount of split packages anyway.

Edit:
As to why I would like to find a solution for this. I do not want to push all my assets to a git repo, as git was not build for this and git lfs does not work for multiple project usage as far as I know.
Meaning when pulling a project, I would need to also pull all assets separately, which I would like to automate. If I have x asset packs within a project, I do not want to manually go through x assets and add them to the project, each letting unity load quite long. Therefore I would like to add all packages before the project is even opened with unity.

Comment: I think you need to rexplain in terms of why.  you can make unity assets, unity packages, what is wrong with those?

Comment: OP you could use [gitmodules](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitmodules)

Comment: @BugFinder You are right, I have updated the question to give more context.

Comment: @DeanVanGreunen This would require me to create a repo for each package and adding each repo as a submodule. Possible but this sounds rather ugly as more and more packages would be added.

Comment: well you can make unity packages, and store them on github, and add them to the json file and it will load them. At some point the loading has to happen

Comment: Can you elaborate? Which json file are you referring too? And as mentioned in the comment above, I would like to avoid submodules or a repo for each possible package. If this is actually how it should be done, I am very suprised, as as far as I know git shouldnt be used for binary files and git lfs was not made to be used as a package management system.
Isn't there an actual solution which is used by companies or something?

Comment: If you follow unity's package format (which is basically an NPM-like structure https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/CustomPackages.html) you can have the Package Manager pick it up from a Git URL just fine https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/upm-ui-giturl.html including if some of the binary content is on LFS

Comment: Use git large file system a.k.a GIT LFS for large files. Don't mess with merging scenes and try to work with prefabs and i mean different versions of prefabs. Later on you could see if you could handle assets as bundles. In this case you should add Components (scripts) per script, to make sure you have the right component at the right time.

Comment: That explains how I can create and use packages within unity which wasn't my question. I have also mentioned that git lfs is not the solution for a number of reasons.